# CSS Transition: How can I make a div move, pause, and then reverse direction with 1 transition?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I can use a simple transition to move a div's left value

```
transition: left 1s linear .5s
```

but how can I, using just 1 transition, make a div move left, pause, then move back again?

I've been having trouble finding out how to do this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It seems animations are the way to go:

http://codepen.io/graygilmore/pen/8d8b41ed278d061764b3df531223a0e1

HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}

.gogogo {
  animation: tumble 4s linear;
}

@keyframes tumble {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
  }

  30%,
  60% {
    top: 300px;
    left: 300px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
  }

  100% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

Coffeescript:

```
$(".box").on "click", ->
  $(".box").toggleClass("gogogo")
```

Comment: Yep, this is the way to go... although the top should stay at 0 to do what he asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this. If you check out [this link](http://easings.net/) you can see that many different ways to transition exist but they all require two distinct states to transition between. I think you will need to use two of them.